# Common service for READ and WRITE - CQRS + DDD

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Hey I have an aggregate root with some properties which need to be calculated - **totals**.
These properties are not saved, but are needed to fill a **readDto** while *seeding* and an **Event** for the EventStore when the aggregateRoot is *created* or *updated*.

Is it a good practice to have a COMMON service between the **read** and the **write** part, which will calculate these **totals** and provide them to dtos or events or wherever they are needed ?

Answer (score 1):

> to have a COMMON service

It's permissible to use any valid technique you'd normally use to effect the DRY principle (but bearing in mind to temper this with the [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming))).

Sometimes, this means copying a file of helpers between the write/decision process and a projection service. Sometimes you might even compile those into a single helper library. Sometimes is a piece of code in a dynamic language that can be run against an instance of an event (or series of events being folded) hydrated in the context of the decision process, the projection service or a reader process.

There is no fundamental law that says there must be exactly one thing (a compiled piece of code running as single service) which owns the rule - for starters, what happens if you want to deploy an update to that service without downtime?

In short - there is no hard and fast rule; any such a one size fits all prescriptive recipe would have hundreds of exceptions. A bit like an enterprise wide universal data model ;)

> I am not that afraid of breaking DRY principle by using a single service.
>
> My real concern is about if using common read/write stuff is against
> the CQRS pattern.

Quite often this can be legitimate - readers and writers both observe the stream of events in order to infer ('fold') a rolling state. Readers may be exposing contextual information which can be used to drive 'users' to formulate commands representing desired actions/state transitions, which necessarily have a degree of overlap. The key thing is that decision making itself should only live on the write side (bu this fits well with the general principle that a command should normally not result in feedback - typically it should be idempotently processable with any validation etc. being a fait accomplit security-driven double check)

> And secondly if using logic in the read part is against the CQRS pattern.

One typically agreed no-no is having conditional logic in the fold which maintains the rolling state - this should be simple mechanical accumulation.

For a projection and/or denormalizer which is maintaining an eventually consistent read-only view based on observing the events will often be using overlapping simple projection logic. If that logic gets complex, involves transactions etc., that's a design smell though - if the Events represent what's going on naturally and not contrived, they should tend to be relatively straightforward to map/project - you should really only be 'indexing' them or laying them out in a form appropriate for the given necessities of the reader.

If you're ending up with complex flows in the projection system, that's a sign you probably have multiple different readers and should perhaps consider separate projections to that end (i.e. kinda like the Interface Segregation Principle)

Comment: Hey Ruben,
I am not that afraid of breaking DRY principle by using a single service. My real concern is about if using common read/write stuff is against the CQRS pattern.
And secondly if using logic in the read part is against the CQRS pattern.

Comment: @IvelinMatev Added a rambling response - talking in generalities about CQRS is a recipe for that. If you have a real world example of a real world domain, feel free to post a followup question and I or someone else will answer. If you're interested in more general discussions in this space, the DDD-CQRS-ES slack is a great resource (ggl search to find the invite site)